# Serialize response from post async .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to modify the response when serialized. `TimeJoined` is returned as a string in format `hh:mm (GMT +_)` and I want to modify as a 24h format, in the instance below would be `14:46`

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TimeJoined { get; set; } // "12:46 (GMT +2)"
}

public async Task<Person> GetPerson()
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, new { id = "aydt344d" });
    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>();
}
```

Comment: if we forget the 24h format, how you are doing it today?

Comment: i return it as it is and postprocess in frontend. I was just wondering if it is possible to do it in the backend

Comment: How do you know whether it's am or pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key for 24h is in the following string format:

```
hh for 12h format
HH for 24h format
z is for time zone
```

Lets put that together, something like:

```
string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm ({0} z)"), "GMT");
```

To put that in your person object you can do something like:

```
var person = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>(); 
person.TimeJoined = string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm ({0} z)"), "GMT");
return person;
```

Or take that format and use it in your customer serializer as the other answer mentioned, that way you can use it overall.

Of course, you can also make a static method and re-used it as well.

Testing that will give time format like this:

```
15:00 (GMT +2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [Custom Json Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#registration-sample---converters-collection)

After that, you can create a [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0) (it can be globally) and pass it to `ReadFromJsonAsync` as a parameter. done!

however, in the Person class the `TimeJoined` is `string` so you will need to use `TimeSpan` or parse time and reformat it to that you want

Comment: I like this answer as a general solution.